# Matlab: save an int8 vector in a binary file

Tags: matlab, binary, integer, byte

Hello I would like to get some help with something please:

I'm trying to make readable a int8 vector (which was actually retrieved from an already binary .mat file via a MySQL database).

I'd like to do something like:

```
fileId = fopen(fileName, 'w');
fwrite(fileId, vector,'uint8');
fclose(fileId);
load(fileName);
```

But Matlab throws an error "File may be corrupt".

The idea behind this,  is to use a central database to stock our .mat files.

vector is a `[ 306624x1 int8]` and looks like:

vector = [77;65;84 ...

Thanks for any help

### Edit

I'm continuing with this task, the solution that @Rotem gave me works perfectly. 
I have millions of .mat files, which are really slow to read from a hard drive.

So, I have changed to a database and in order to retrieve these files I do mysql queries (this is much faster).

I recover each file as a vector of bytes, then I write in a local hard drive and reloaded using load().

@Rotem helped me with that, but now I'm facing the problem of space disc.
There is a way to perform this conversion directly without passing through fwrite - load?

Thanks for the lights!

Comment: You don't want `fwrite`, you want [`save`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) if your goal is a MAT file.

Comment: Are you trying to create a database of binary representations of .mat files? You are using fwrite when your problem says you are reading in data?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough.
The problem is not the reading. 
My starting point is an uint8-vector which has the bytes of a binary (.mat) file (each component of the vector is a byte).

What I'm trying to do is to rebuild the file from this sequence of bytes.

That's why my try was to re-write this vector in a binary .mat file and trying to load it to recover the inicial data on the file.

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say I got the motivation behind it...

Check the following code sample:

```
%Create sample mat file with saved matrix A.
A = magic(3);
save('A.mat', 'A');
clear A; %Note: A is cleared from Matlab Workspace.

%Read A.mat to uint8 vector:
f = fopen('A.mat', 'r');
vector = fread(f, '*uint8'); %Use '*uint8' to keep vector in class uint8.
fclose(f);

%Write vector to B.mat as binary file:
f = fopen('B.mat', 'w');
fwrite(f, vector);
fclose(f);

%Load B.mat as mat file:
load('B.mat');

%Display A matrix (loaded from B.mat).
A
```

`A =`

`8     1     6`
`3     5     7`
`4     9     2`

Comment: Thanks for your help, thanks to you I realized that a typecast was missing in my code: int8 -> uint8.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Rotem. Do you know a method to read the data directly from the vector instead? (I edited my question explaning better my issue). Thanks for you help.

Comment: I don't know of such method. Can't you simply delete MAT file after loading?